# How to insert Greek letters (having trouble with \greekletter)

Tags: greek

This is my code:

```
\begin{equations}
\begin{align}
\lamba = \frac{x}{2}
\end{align}
\end{equations}
```

But `\lamba` appears just as a blank space.

Comment: You seem to have several mistakes: `\lamba` = `\lambda`? it should be `\begin-\end{equation}`, not "equations", and why do you use `align`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` that illustrates your problem. And to add to @PeterJansson comment: Do not use the `align` environment inside another math-mode environment. `align` introduces math-mode on its own.

Answer (score 8):

You would find comprehensive documentation [online](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) about typesetting equations. You can also [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=latex+math+equations+typeset) for examples, you'll find several examples along with explanation. One such compilation is by [Stefan M. Moser](http://moser.cm.nctu.edu.tw/docs/typeset_equations.pdf).

Below is a MWE to help you get started.

You would have to use the `amsmath` package.

To typeset inline equations, you may use the LaTeX shorthand `\(...\)` or the Tex shorthand `$...$`. For numbered equations, you would have to use the `equation` environment. See below for examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
We can use the \LaTeX~shorthand for inline equations such as \( \alpha = \beta +
\gamma + \lambda \).

For numbered equations we can use the \texttt{equation} environment.
  \begin{equation}
    \alpha = \beta + \gamma + \lambda
  \end{equation}

If we do not want the equations to be numbered, we may use the
\texttt{equation*} environment.
    \begin{equation*}
    \alpha = \beta + \gamma + \lambda
  \end{equation*}

The \texttt{align} and/or \texttt{eqnarray} environment is used to group together multiple
equations and align them using \texttt{\&}
\begin{align}
    \alpha &= \beta + \gamma * \lambda \\
    \theta &= \frac{\alpha}{4}
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You should almost always avoid using `eqnarray`. See [eqnarray vs. align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/2693).